# Calling to UpdateModel in a controller is follow MVC pattern?? How could I do the same in the model layer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2

newbie writing, I'm new to MVC 2 C# and using EntityFramework with LINQ.

In many examples (including the MVC 2 MusicStore of Microsoft) I've noticed that the Database updates are made in the Controllers layers. For example If I want to update a Database Product I call to UpdateModel(product,"Products" ) and call to SaveChanges() in the ProductController class

Ok, simple and easy but **is this following MVC "traditional" pattern** ??

Instead of this, I try to delegate the responsibility to the ProductModel class (I've made it with success in Adding and Deleting with AutoMapper) but I don't find the way to update from the model 
I tried something like

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductModels>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ProductModels, Product>();
        var p = Mapper.Map<Product, ProductModels>(prod);

        productosBD.AttachTo("Products", p); 
        productosBD.SaveChanges();
```

but no way...

Could somebody tell me how can I update an entity in the model layer??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP NET MVC has evolved a lot from version 1 Beta to version 2 and now version 3 although 2 and 3 are much more similar.

A lot of such samples are related to MVC 1 - something I learnt the hard way. I am pretty new to ASP NET MVC but realised in MVC 2, **ModelBinder** looks after updating the model so normally if you define your method signature as your model, you do not need to call `UpdateModel`.

For example:

```
 public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
 {
      ... // no need to call UpdateModel
```

However if you define it like this, then you need to do that:

```
 public ActionResult Create(int id, FormCollection collection)
 {
      MyModel model = Repository.Get(id); // in your case EF productosBD.Where(x=>x.Id = id)
      UpdateMode(model, collection);
      Repository.Save(model);
```

In terms of where the update happens, yes, it will happen in your controller but it depends if you use a Repository pattern or use the bare database context. I personally use a `ServiceProxy` which then talks to a WCF Service which talks to a `Manager` which uses a `Repository` to do that.

Comment: I think ModelBinder did the same thing in ASP.NET MVC 1.

Comment: Never used MVC 1 but all the examples I have seen for MVC 1 used UpdateModel.

Comment: I founded I need to call to ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p,System.Data.EntityState.Modified); in order to set the EntityState to modified. So I added this to the model layer and changed the controller as you wrote above, but now it's shows a NullReferenceException in the Edit.aspx view at the line with ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState.  Any ideas of what's going on??

Comment: Finally I found the answer I write it here for the people with the same problem: the idea is that the context.Attach(product); does not work because the state of the context is not set to Modified (remembering that if we don't update in the controller with UpdateModel() , we don't have the help of the model to follow It's changes), so we have to set it by ourselves with: productosBD.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);  More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896248.aspx